# How to launch the third-party android applications I installed through Intent directly?

Tags: android

we can launch android market application from:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setData("market://details?id=packgename");

startActivity(intent);
```

My question is how to launch the third-party android applications I installed through Intent directly? Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: actually you ain't launching market application in your above example. You are just sending an `intent` that you need to open something with `market://` as url.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do that, you need to find the following info for the application you want to start:

- Package
- Startup Class

You can obtain this info if you start third-party app regularly, and in the LogCat inspect the trace.

Then, you just fill in following intent with the info you obtained:

```
    Intent startupIntent = new Intent();
    ComponentName distantActivity = new ComponentName("com.third.exampleapp", "com.third.exampleapp.StartupClass");
    startupIntent.setComponent(distantActivity);
    startupIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startActivity(startupIntent);
```

Please note that it is very bad practice to start standard Android system Intents this way.