# How to filter nonsystem application from all installed applications

Tags: android

I have the following code and it works well to fetch the details of all applications installed in android but when i use a filter using isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo) it gives force close.

```
try {
    lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    {
        List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            if (isSystemPackage(rInfo)) {
                results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                        .loadLabel(pm).toString());
            }

        }
    }
} catch(Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(), 4000).show();
}
```

it generates force closed

isSystemPackage() code is

```
private boolean isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo ri){
    return ((ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags&ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)!=0)?   
       true:false;
}
```

I tried to debug it but can't able to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got my Answer, This is for others to use this code.

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> list = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
      for (int n=0;n<list.size();n++) {
          if((list.get(n).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)!=1)
          {
       results.add(list.get(n).loadLabel(pm).toString());
       Log.w("Installed Applications", list.get(n).loadLabel(pm).toString());
          }

      }
```

cheers :)

Comment: :) now i have question, how to implement a click or touch listener on listView to open the application.

Comment: I have two useful answers on that. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181699/how-to-launch-the-third-party-android-applications-i-installed-through-intent-dir/4182357#4182357 and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750380/android-listview-with-delete-button/3750594#3750594. There should be everything you need. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah but it also filters out apps like the android Camera app. How do I make it so that doesn't get left out?

Comment: I had gotten to the point of needing to check the flags (figured that part out), but with multiple flags, I really didn't know how to filter it. What does the & operator mean here?

Comment: @phil: its bitwise AND operator here, ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM=1 is for system application.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this approach. It works for me:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> applications = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
for (int n=0; n < applications.size(); n++)
{
    if ((applications.get(n).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 1)
    {
        Log.i(tag , "Non-System Aplication name " + applications.get(n).name);
    }
}
```