# How can you send an entire search request to the GoogleTV or launch an app into a particular view?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-tv

I've been reading the android and google TV docs for a bit now, and I can't seem to find much information on this.  Google mentions building Multiscreen apps for Google TV, but their [Android remote app example](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/) mostly just sends keystrokes to the google tv after you have navigated around using the directional pad.

I'm curious how you would send requests to the google TV that could do things like the following:

- Type a full string on the phone (i.e. "cats on a skateboard") and send the entire search query to the GoogleTV (as opposed to sending each individual keystroke to the google TV)
- Press a button on the phone that launches a specific video on an app like Netflix or Youtube, etc

Are these examples doable, and if so, how?  I was reading about [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), but it wasn't that clear to me.  I know this is an involved question, but I appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

To send a string to search use [Anymote's sendData event](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/index#dataevent).

To launch an app, convert the Intent to launch that app into a Uri, using [Intent.toUri()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#toUri%28int%29) method and then send it to the TV using [Anymote's fling event](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/index#flingevents).

I will publish a simpler sample app for Anymote in a week or two. Meanwhile please follow:
http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/tvremote/protocol/AnymoteSender.java

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a resource that describes the different Intents/URIs for different apps?  Where can one find what Intents, Actions, etc are supported by particular apps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181699/how-to-launch-the-third-party-android-applications-i-installed-through-intent-di

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518407/android-starting-an-activity-for-a-different-third-party-app